# Make an entire user control clickable through a command binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'd like to make an entire user control respond to a touch/click event. And, I want to make it happen through a view model binding to a command.

I am trying to make the ENTIRE contents of the user control clickable but I don't know where to bind the command. I know how to bind a button to a command, but essentially, I want the entire control to be a button.

Here is the contents of the user control

```
<Grid x:Name="gridContent1" Margin="5,0,20,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ShortName}"  />
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Value}" ContentStringFormat="0.000"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding UnitOfMeasurement}"  />
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Source="{Binding TrendDirection, Converter={StaticResource converterTrendDirection}}" Style="{StaticResource TrendImage}" Width="48" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```

This is what a list of the controls looks like once it is bound to data.

[image: User control contents (list)]

I am trying to allow the user to click on the control and go to a details chart view of the measurement.

The view model has a command already defined so I would like to bind to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good scenario for using Behaviors and/or triggers. Here is a simple sample made with Blend and BlendSDK for WPF:

A user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BehaviorSample.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BehaviorSample"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="Red"/>
</UserControl>
```

The viewmodel:

using System.Windows;

```
namespace BehaviorSample
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public void SomeMethod() => MessageBox.Show("Hi there!");
    }
}
```

Main window xaml:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BehaviorSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then we need to add the following namespaces to our main window xaml:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

And we change our markup like following:

```
  <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="SomeMethod" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </local:MyUserControl>
    </Grid>
```

Here we are using the **CallMethodAction** action, but you can use a custom behavior if you want.

Notice that you can just write the markup by hand but you may want to try to use Blend for this as is easier.

**EDIT**
There are out there several third party solutions that implement an **event to command behavior** like MvvmLight, Devexpress WPF, etc. But if you do not want to add extra dependencies the solution shown must be fine

**EDIT. Using MvvmLight EventToCommand trigger action**

Main window xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BehaviorSample"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
    x:Class="BehaviorSample.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <!--<ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="SomeMethod" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />-->
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=SomeCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </local:MyUserControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Nottice we added the following namespace:

```
 xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
```

And in our viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    //public void SomeMethod() => MessageBox.Show("Hi there!");

    public RelayCommand SomeCommand => new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("Hi there!"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I'm actually using MVVMLight (RelayCommand) does that make it easier/different?  I have the whole thing working with a button in the control...I'd just like the whole control to take the place of the button

Comment: @Paul, I have edited the answer to show how it would look using MvvmLight's EventToCommand. As you can see it is almost the same: Instead of CallMethodAction we use EventToCommand action, instead of having a method to call we have a RelayCommand to execute =)

Comment: May the force be with you ;)